# Image Tracking (nft) on Ar.js cannot showing 3d object

Tags: javascript, 3d, augmented-reality, ar.js

I have been trying to showing up 3d object on AR.js custom image (image tracking). what I believe is something wrong with my code. this NFT has been build by NFT marker and the object still didn't show up. Could you guys please check if there is any some inappropriate syntax?

```
<script
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/aframevr/aframe@1c2407b26c61958baa93967b5412487cd94b290b/dist/aframe-master.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar-nft.js"></script>



<!-- style for the loader -->
<style>
  .arjs-loader div {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    color: white;
  }

  #check-detect {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 10%;
    z-index: 9999;
    color: red;
    font-size: 3em;

  }
</style>

<script>
  addEventListener('markerFound', () => {
    document.querySelector("#check-detect").innerHTML = 'marker found '
    // + JSON.stringify(arguments)
  })

  addEventListener('markerLost', () => {
    document.querySelector("#check-detect").innerHTML = 'marker lost'
  })
</script>

<body style="margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;">
  <!-- minimal loader shown until image descriptors are loaded. Loading may take a while according to the device computational power -->
  <div class="arjs-loader">
    <div>Loading, please wait...</div>
  </div>

  <div id="check-detect">
    ---
  </div>

  <a-scene vr-mode-ui="enabled: false;" renderer="logarithmicDepthBuffer: true;" embedded
    arjs="trackingMethod: best; sourceType: webcam;debugUIEnabled: false;">
    <!-- a-nft is the anchor that defines an Image Tracking entity -->
    <!-- on 'url' use the path to the Image Descriptors created before. -->
    <!-- the path should end with the name without the extension e.g. if file is 'pinball.fset' the path should end with 'pinball' -->
    <a-text value="adsdsadsasd" anchor="center" color="red" position="0 1.3 20"></a-text>
    <a-nft type="nft" url="../image-markers/aquaa" smooth="true" smoothCount="10" smoothTolerance=".01"
      smoothThreshold="5">
      <!-- as a child of the a-nft entity, you can define the content to show. here's a GLTF model entity -->
      <a-entity gltf-model="../model/Batleth.gltf" scale="5 5 5" position="50 150 100">
      </a-entity>


    </a-nft>
    <!-- static camera that moves according to the device movemenents -->
    <a-entity camera></a-entity>
  </a-scene>


</body>
```